# VBA Excel how to exclude cell value with specified part of the string

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I set an IF statement for increasing my value in the first cell, when the string in the other cell contains somewhere the number "2". The problem is that sometimes that string includes "12f" or "24f", which I don't want to affect the first cell.

I've prepared the code like this:

```
   If Range("D39").Value Like "*2*" Or Range("C39").Value = 2 Or Range("D39").Value <> Like "*f12*" 
        Then
        Range("C38").Value = 2
     Else
        Range("C38").Value = 1
     End If
```

which doesn't work unfortunately

Moreover the similar solution here:

[Excluding certain cell values from if statement macro vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677454/excluding-certain-cell-values-from-if-statement-macro-vba)

is unclear to me.

Is there an option to exclude the string, which contains "12f" or "24f"?

**UPDATE**

The following code:

```
  If Range("D39").Value Like "*2*" Or Range("C39").Value = 2 And Not 
  Range("D39").Value Like "*12f*" Then
        Range("C38").Value = 2
    Else
        Range("C38").Value = 1
    End If
```

Doesn't work either. I keep on getting value 2 instead of one having "12f" in my string

Comment: You can use `InStr`, or `Not ... Like`.

Comment: What do you want to do with cells which have values like 123412f?

Comment: Did you mean
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php
?
Where in my code should I put it? Could it be like: Or Not Range("D39").Value like...?

Comment: `And`, not `Or`. If you want to use `InStr`, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function).

Comment: I tried:
If Range("D39").Value Like "*2*" Or Range("C39").Value = 2 and Range ("C39").Value not Like "*12f*" Then
but i am getting "Expected expression" error

Comment: @SiddharthRout the only values which I can get are 12f or 24f. I want to exclude them from the condition.

Comment: I am slighty confused. Can you give me couple of values that can be in the cells? @MKR